# Creating a function handle out of the input of the parent function?

Tags: matlab, concatenation, anonymous-function, type-conversion

forgive me if the answer is this is terribly obvious or if there's a much better way to do this.

I'm trying to make a function that accepts a function of x (e.g. x^2 + 5x + 2), and use that input to create a function handle. That way I can use that function for whatever else I need it to do.

I think the problem is just that I don't know what all the different function types are, and I don't understand how to "concatenate" the "@(x)" and the input function correctly to make the function handle.

Here's what I tried:

```
function test(input1)

function_1 = @(x) + input1

end
```

It says that input1 is of type double, even if it's just a letter.

And if I try to enter the input as a string and convert it to symbolic data, I just get an array of numbers for the concatentaion.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific. It is entirely possible to create anonymous functions in different ways, but how you do it will depend on the particular type of input. One useful function you could look at is `matlabFunction` which converts a symbolic function into an anonymous function.

Comment: I'm reluctant to even mention it, but there's the deprecated `inline` that converts an expression into an anonymous function. Also `str2func` might work, but it will generate a warning that using `str2fun('2*x')` is deprecated as well. Just use regular function handles!

Comment: @Amro  My first instinct was to try `str2func`, but I observed: `Warning: The input to STR2FUNC "2*x" is not a valid function name. This will generate an error in a future release. `  :(  Only `str2func('@(x)2*x')` works, which defeats the purpose of doing it that way.  I'm allergic to `inline` (and most other deprecated functions).  Undocumented on the other hand...

Comment: me too, I only mentioned it for completeness. I consider it in the same category as "eval" (that is avoid it at all costs)! Like many questions of this kind, it can answered by using an `eval`-based solution... However a better advice would be to suggest that the OP rethinks his approach. For that we need to know what is it that the OP is trying to achieve here...

Comment: @Amro  Agreed - that's why I ultimately suggest passing a function handle rather than a string.  However, I can see using `eval` or `str2func` if the goal is to input a function through a GUI, or input prompt, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing a string probably won't get you what you want, or it will get ugly.

This might be off topic, but it's important to understand that anonymous functions store the value of non-input variables at the time of creation.  Any values that you want to change on each call to the function need to be input arguments.

```
>> a = pi;
>> fun = @(x) x * a;
>> fun(2)
ans =

    6.2832
```

You can see the stored values as follows,

```
>> fi = functions(fun)
fi = 
     function: '@(x)x*a'
         type: 'anonymous'
         file: ''
    workspace: {[1x1 struct]}
>> fi.workspace{1}
ans = 
    a: 3.1416
```

If your intention is to have another input argument, just have two input arguments:

```
>> fun = @(x,y) x * y;
>> fun(2,pi)
ans =
    6.2832
```

However, you can pass a function handle to a function, and then call it. Perhaps this is what you're after:

```
function myfun = funTester(fh,x)
% presumably do something useful here
myfun = fh(x);

end
```

For example,

```
>> fun = @(x) x.^2 + 5*x + 2
fun = 
    @(x)x.^2+5*x+2
>> funTester(fun,-2)
ans =
    -4
```

Final thought: Construct a handle with `eval`:

```
>> expression  = 'x^2 + 5*x + 2';
>> eval(['h = @(x) ' expression])  % put this in your function
h = 
    @(x)x^2+5*x+2
```

Or `str2func`, (thanks Luis Mendo)

```
h = str2func(['@(x)' expression])
```

Either way it's not too pretty, hence my suggestion to just pass a handle.

Comment: @PeterHuddleston Added the last part about `eval`, but I suspect that's not the best solution for you.

Comment: Why not just `str2func(['@(x)' input1])` (where of course `input1` should contain valid syntax; the OP is missing a `*`)

Comment: @LuisMendo Sure that too. Then I guess my suggestion would be to skip both approaches and just require `input1` to be a proper function handle to begin with.  :)

Comment: @chappjc yea, I was using input from a GUI. I'm using str2func right now and will see if any issues pop up. Thanks a lot for your help!